# case should be opened under that contact

Tags: case, email2case, case-object, casefeed

I am a bit new in salesforce so I am sorry If the question is silly.

I want to make a rule that if I have a new case opened by an address that already belongs to a contact in the system , the case should be opened under that contact

How do I do that ?
thank you

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE. user24136. The only "silly question" is the one that isn't asked or that you could answer yourself by looking at the documentation. Being new, the documentation can be rather daunting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to `email addresses`, according to the Salesforce Help page [Working with Case Emails](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cases_email.htm&language=en_US):

> If an inbound email does not contain the email address of an existing contact, then the Web Name field on the case is automatically updated with the name in the From field of the email, and the Web Email field on the case is automatically updated with the address provided in the inbound email.

If this isn't the behavior you're seeing, then I recommend you review these two documents: [Enabling and Configuring On-Demand Email-to-Case](http://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01530000001x32vAAA) and [Knowledge Article 000006526 - How does Email-to-case match an incoming email to an existing contact](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006526&language=en_US).